# Recursion vs. iteration in Lisp macro

Tags: beginner, lisp, common-lisp

I've been programming Clojure for a little while and recently started learning Common Lisp. One of my favorite things about Clojure is the threading operator `->`, which greatly simplifies long chains of nested function calls. Naturally I wanted to have this in Common Lisp.

I found an implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/kriyative/2030582):

> ```
> (defmacro -> (x &rest args)
>   (destructuring-bind (form &rest more)
>       args
>     (cond
>       (more `(-> (-> ,x ,form) ,@more))
>       ((and (consp form)
>             (or (eq (car form) 'lambda)
>                 (eq (car form) 'function)))
>        `(funcall ,form ,x))
>       ((consp form) `(,(car form) ,x ,@(cdr form)))
>       (form `(,form ,x))
>       (t x))))
> ```

This uses a recursive macro expansion; I've read that it's better to use iteration over recursion in CL when you can, so I wrote my own version:

```
(defmacro -> (x &rest forms)
  (labels ((expand-form (x form)
             (if (consp form)
                 (if (or (eq (car form) 'lambda)
                         (eq (car form) 'function))
                     `(funcall ,form ,x)
                     `(,(car form) ,x ,@(cdr form)))
                 `(,form ,x))))
    (do ((forms forms (cdr forms))
         (x x (expand-form x (car forms))))
        ((not forms) x))))
```

I'm relatively new to Lisp so I don't know how to judge which way is better. Any comments, suggestions?

EDIT: I knew something was fishy! You don't have to use any looping constructs at all, a plain old `reduce` will cut it:

```
(defmacro -> (x &rest forms)
  (flet ((expand-form (x form)
           (cond
             ((atom form)
              `(,form ,x))
             ((member (car form) '(lambda function))
              `(funcall ,form ,x))
             (t
              `(,(car form) ,x ,@(cdr form))))))
    (reduce #'expand-form forms :initial-value x)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't be so focused on iteration vs. recursion; use what is
necessary and convenient.  For macros in general you should care about
clarity of the macro and the generated code, performance of the macro
code itself comes way last in general.

Now to add only two things to the discussion, using `DO` is not
particularly common because in most cases there are better options;
personally I always have to look up the meaning of all the clauses of
`DO`, which is why I am not a fan of it.  The other thing is to use
`COND` to be a bit more concise if your `IF` clauses allow for it.

Since you now already have a good version of the first solution, the
following would be a way to do those things for the iterative solution:

```
(defmacro -> (x &rest forms)
  (flet ((expand-form (x form)
           (cond
             ((atom form)
              `(,form ,x))
             ((member (car form) '(lambda function))
              `(funcall ,form ,x))
             (T `(,(car form) ,x ,@(cdr form))))))
    (loop
      for form in forms
      for y = (expand-form x form)
        then (expand-form y form)
      finally (return y))))
```

Note that I've switched `(not (consp x))` to `(atom x)`; now the `LOOP` is
less concise then the `DO`, but I'd argue that it's more obvious what is
happening with it, YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I like the way you've rewritten the macro. I'm not favoring iteration over recursion for performance; I find it easier to understand this way. Also, I get the generated code with one `macroexpand` rather than with a code walker.

Comment: Why use 'sub on forms' and later 'car sub'? Why not just use 'sub in forms'?

Comment: ... yes, I don't know why I wrote that, thanks @RainerJoswig.

Comment: @korrok yes, that's basically why I often prefer the iterative version as well.  If you didn't already knew, there is also `macroexpand-all`, not a standard function, but nevertheless used to completely expand an expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first version is slightly more elegant and looks okay to me.

In the second version, I would replace `LABELS` with `FLET`. `LABELS` would indicate some kind of recursion.

Generally I would also think if the nested expansion is something I would want, vs. an expansion into a `LET*` form.

I would also replace `CAR` and `CDR` with `FIRST` and `REST`.

The `DESTRUCTURING-BIND` is also not necessary:

```
(defmacro -> (x form &rest more)
  (cond (more
         `(-> (-> ,x ,form) ,@more))
        ((and (consp form)
              (member (first form) '(lambda function)))
         `(funcall ,form ,x))
        ((consp form)
         `(,(first form) ,x ,@(rest form)))
        (form
         `(,form ,x))
        (t x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `labels` here. To me, the use of `labels` or similar definition inside a definition is justified if I need to reuse the same function inside another function, or if it will in some sense make it more clear.

So, here's, for the sake of diversity, a version that uses `iterate` package.

```
(defmacro -> (x &rest forms)
  (iter
    (for form :in forms)
    (for y :=
        (case (car (when (consp form) form))
          ((lambda function) `(funcall ,form ,x))
          ('nil `(,form ,x))
          (otherwise `(,(car form) ,x ,@(cdr form)))))
    (setf x y)
    (finally (return y))))
```